# Windows 10 wants installation disk after using restore point?

Tags: windows-10

I was just at a customers house, trying to solve a malware issue. I went through my usual steps like removing malware programs, deleting services, removing files manually and deleting registry entries related to the malware.

This all went fine, but then I needed to install Kaspersky for future cleaning and protection. It kept telling me that it couldn't install because of missing digital signature. I went to talk to the support and they gave me a solution. Long story short, it didn't work.

So I decided, why not use the restore function and go back to a previous state before he installed the malware. So I did, leaving the costumer to it while it did so.

I've just been called by my boss saying the costumer called back, and the computer now wants an installation disc. Can't boot otherwise.

Why would this happen? I need to go back there next week and solve it but I'm honestly dumbfounded.

Comment: "Why would this happen?" - The image on the system is either not applicable and/or not accessible to the installation in question or it simply is corrupt.  Without exact specifics, which you can't seem to provide until next week, you might have to wait for an answer that indicates a way forward to this problem.  I am obviously talking about the image used by the Refresh feature within Windows 10.

Comment: Did you recognise the malware?

Comment: @biswa UCBrowser, AVBoost and some Russian malware called EpicNet I think. Or something of the sorts.

Comment: @ramhound so possibly a damaged image. Okay. Will probably have to reinstall the guys computer then :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you reinstall 10,  saw some steps that I would recommend you use.

You can use this steps if you're able to successfully boot the computer.

> - Step 1: Connect your bootable Windows 10 USB to your PC. If you have a bootable DVD of Windows 10, please insert the same in the optical drive.

And if you have Windows 10 ISO image file, browse to the folder containing the ISO file, right-click on it, and then click Mount option to open the contents of the ISO image in File Explorer (Windows Explorer).

If you don’t have Windows 10 USB, DVD or ISO image, please download Windows 10 ISO image from Microsoft using the official Windows 10 Media Creation Tool. The tool, with default settings, downloads the edition and type (32-bit or 64-bit) of Windows 10 currently installed on the customer's PC.

> - Step 2: Open **This PC (My Computer)**, right-click on the USB or DVD drive, click Open in new window option.

Similarly, if you have mounted an ISO image of Windows 10, please right-click on the mounted drive in This PC, click Open in new window option.

> - Step 3: Double-click on the Setup.exe file. Click Yes when you see the User Account Control dialog.
> - Step 4: In a few seconds, you will see Get important updates screen with two options:

`Download and install updates (recommended)`

`Not right now`

> If the PC is connected to the internet, I recommend you select the first radio button labelled **Download and install updates (recommended)**.

If you want, you may uncheck the box labelled I want to help make the installation of Windows better to avoid sending anonymous data to Microsoft about the installation.

Select an option and then click Next button.

> - Step 5: Upon clicking the Next button, the setup will start checking for updates. If you selected Not right now option in the previous step, you won’t see this screen.

The tool might take tens of minutes to check for updates.

> - Step 6: Next, you will see the License terms screen where you need to click the Accept button to proceed further.
>
> Upon clicking the Accept button, the setup might look for updates and download them, if available.
>
> You might see the following Making sure you are ready to install screen for a few minutes. At this point, the setup checks your PC can run Windows 10 and also checks if there is sufficient space required for the operation.
>
> - Step 7: Finally, you will see the Choose what to keep or Ready to install screen.

If you get the Ready to install screen, click the link labelled Change what to keep, and then select **Keep personal files and apps** (if you don’t want to lose apps installed from the Store, and so that after the installation, you won't have to pass through the stress of explaining to the customer why you need to reinstall the Windows). Click **Next** button. The setup will once again make sure that you’re ready to install.

> And if you get Choose what to keep screen screen instead, you will see three options:

```
Keep personal files and apps

Keep personal files only

Nothing
```

> But if you will want to reinstall Windows 10 without deleting your files, select the second option labelled **Keep personal files only** option, (but **NOTE**: this option will delete all you apps) before clicking the Next button.
>
> - Step 8: Finally, you will see the Ready to install screen once again, this time with Install button.
>
> Click the **Install** button to begin installing/reinstalling Windows 10. You will see the following Installing Windows 10 screen for a few minutes. Your PC might restart several times.
>
> Once the installation is done, you will see the options to select your country, language, keyboard layout, and time zone.
>
> - Step 9: When you see the following screen, click on **Customize settings** link instead of the large **Use Express Settings** button to change default privacy settings. Read all settings carefully and keep them on or turn off. Of course, you can change these settings later under Settings app.
>
> You will be asked to sign in using your Microsoft account, and if you don’t want install and use Windows 10 using a Microsoft account, you can create a new local user account.

As said before, you will not be asked to activate Windows 10 again after the reinstallation if you’re using an activated install of Windows 10. If you face any activation issues, which you should not while using a genuine Windows 10, please chat with Microsoft support using the Contact Support app. To open it, please type Contact Support in the Start menu or taskbar search box and then press Enter key.

You can also read more in case of any other further challenge at [Windows 10](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-without-losing-data/)

But if you're not able to boot the computer, you will have to insert the Windows 10 bootable DVD or USB drive, then you boot from it and follow the instructions, but you will have to select keep personal files so that you don't end up totally formatting the customer's computer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I knew most of this at least, but good to see it typed out. I'll have to reinstall for sure it seems like.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry for the mishap though

Comment: I appreciate the effort :)